# Является ли сортировка посредством слияния списков - реальным слиянием списков?

Tags: алгоритм

Является ли сортировка посредством слияния списков - реальным слиянием списков? Ведь по сути здесь добавляются поля связи с помощью которых и будет происходить сортировка, никакие манипуляции с записями мы не делаем(не передвигаем). И просто, после всего алгоритма делаем внутреннее слияние. (Кнут 3 том, программа L)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если у вас вопрос по коду - приводите код. Если по алгоритму - приводите алгоритм. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. В данном виде предмета вопроса в вопросе нет, а значит ответить на него нельзя.

Comment: Элементы и связи между ними - это и есть список. Когда меняются связи - меняется список. Так что да, является.

Comment: @insolor получается здесь один список или их все же два? стало интересно, похоже что используется один

Comment: @insolor они объединяются в конце алгоритма или походу выполнения?

Comment: Ну в общем суть сортировки слиянием такая: есть исходный список, в процессе сортировки он разбивается несколько раз на отдельные списки, которые также сортируются, в конце все списки сливаются снова в один.